# Dealing with Illusionist monsters

Tags: diablo-iii

There are some mobs that have the property "Illusionist", which gives them the annoying ability to duplicate themselves multiple times.

The copies seem to have the same amount of health as the original and deal the same damage.

I found this kind of mobs especially hard to beat and have some questions regarding them:

- Are the copies perfect copies or really just illusions to distract you, as the name says? The fact that they can hit you seems to hint at the fact that they are more than that.
- If you kill the original mob, will the copies die?
- If yes, is there any way to distinguish the original from the copies?
- Are the illusions/copies permanent or temporary?
- Do you get additional XP for each copy?
- What is the best strategy against "Illusionist" mobs?

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

In Diablo 3, the monsters have some traits that can be really annoying if you aren’t aware of them. These traits in some cases are also used by the dominions spawned with the monsters.

Each trait can be used after a particular level and has different effects.

Illusionist

Level 26

The illusionist trait lets the monsters create clones. The HP of each clone is same as the original one. These clones however cannot create clones further. It does not grant any extra resistance or damage to the monster.

[Source](http://segmentnext.com/2012/05/14/diablo-3-monster-traits-guide/#ixzz1w63UuvhJ)

Comment: I am pretty sure this is inaccurate. I use a barbarian, and whenever i stand in the middle of a bunch of illusionist champions and use my Revenge ability, all illusions will die, but the "real" monsters will survive. So, the illusions must for certain have less EHP than the actual monsters.

Answer (score 1):

You will notice that the illusions have less life than the "*real deal*". Take this into consideration when picking your skills, have at least 1 skill for crowd control ready.

I find that shooting once into the mob quickly filters out the fake from your preferred target, the illusionist. A different approach would be to mark the illusionist with a skill, for example [Marked for Death](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/marked-for-death) for a Demon Hunter.

The illusions fade over time, but I would not hold my breath for it, it takes a couple of minutes. Don't waste your time on the copies, they do not give any exp, and killing the summoner quickly ends the life of the copies.

Answer (score 0):

- Stick to area of effect abilities when facing illusionists.
- They do count for massacre bonus and give some exp themselves.
- They do die when you focus down the original and there is no way to
  differenciate them from the original afaik.